# PostgreSQL - (declarative) List vs. Range partitioning for DATE's; avoid recheck

Tags: postgresql, performance, partitioning, postgresql-12

***PostgreSQL 12.8 - AWS Aurora***

---

Given a large data-set (*~10B rows / 5TB size*) residing in a partitioned table

```
CREATE TABLE large_table (
  partition_date DATE,
  prime_entity   INT,
  attribute_1    BIGINT,
  attribute_2    FLOAT,
  attribute_3    TEXT,
  value          INT
) PARTITION BY RANGE (partition_date);

CREATE INDEX ON large_table (prime_entity, attribute_1);
CREATE INDEX ON large_table (prime_entity, attribute_2);
CREATE INDEX ON large_table (prime_entity, attribute_3);
```

with *daily* partitioning

```
CREATE TABLE large_table__2023-01-01
  PARTITION OF large_table
  FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-01-01') TO ('2023-01-02')
:
```

and one of the most frequent access pattern (in *conceptualized SQL code*)

```
SELECT
  partition_date,
  prime_entity,
  <AGG>(value) AS agg_attribute
FROM
  large_table
WHERE
  -- mutually exclusive
  -- OPTION 1:
  partition_date
    BETWEEN '<start_date>'
        AND '<end_date>'
  -- OPTION 2:
  partition_date = '<date>'
  AND
  prime_entity = <int>
  AND
  attribute_[1,2,3] IN (<values>)
GROUP BY
  1, 2
;
```

I see a non-trivial amount of overall execution time spent on either

```
Filter: ((partition_date >= '<start_date>'::date) AND (partition_date <= '<end_date>'::date))
```

or

```
Recheck Cond: ((partition_date >= '<start_date>'::date) AND (partition_date <= '<end_date>'::date))
```

---

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` for a `COUNT(*)` with the above query structure and for all data in a single partition:

- [here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/jShc) on the partitioned table, using a range filter on `partition_range`
- [here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/A9ua) on the partition itself without range filter

---

Naturally, the engine needs to validate actual column values against a *range* filter (as in `OPTION 1` above) when querying a *ranged* partition scheme.

However, one may come to think that it make less sense in the case of  the `OPTION 2` filter, considering that individual partition bounds get hit fully inclusive - and subsequently even for `OPTION 1` when taking fully inclusive bounds into account.

Now, I am aware that optimizing arbitrary setups is close to impossible, and I do not expect the planner to guesstimate my intentions here - especially since I chose *Range* partitioning, as a natural scheme for date/time. But in my case I am defining clear partition bounds by `DATE` in a daily partitioning scheme, and would want to benefit from the fact that a recheck on `partition_date` is unnecessary.

**Can I improve the partition scheme or setup otherwise, to improve on the given access pattern and overall performance?**

Obvious ideas:

- staying with the above, the first thing that comes to mind is adding `partition_date` to the indexes, i.e.

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ON large_table (partition_date, prime_entity, attribute_1); --or without attributes?
  ```

  which would certainly increase index size, but might change the planners lookup strategy beneficially
- however, what really interests me is: if I change to ***List*** partitioning on the `DATE` column instead, could `OPTION 2` filters be applied without rechecks when partitions are defined by a list value? But at the same time solve range filters equally performant?
  BTW.: I understand that `partition_range = <int>` is **not** working well for *Range* partitioning, while I probably need to use `partition_range IN ('<dates>')` for 'range' filters in *List* partitioning.

Comment: What makes you think that the check on `partition_date` is responsible for the long duration? Please add the complete `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output to the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe okay, I added in the depesz links to the question body. As I tried to say before I accidentally broke-deleted the question was: by comparing the `Bitmap Heap Scan` nodes, mainly, of a comparison between queries on the partitioned table with range filter and the partitions directly with no range filter.

Comment: The plans are the same, and the difference is only that one query had to read lots of data from a slow disk.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe interesting. The DB was under heavy load when I queried, so I assume this is due to resource management? Since the two plans query the same table. Anyways, obviously I have a filter condition in one plan that, if not used to verify page hits or whatever else that I do not know, seems to be applied on millions of rows - a tiny, yet numerous operation that is not necessary, strictly speaking. Which brings us back to my question.

Comment: I don't believe the filter makes a difference. Try running the queries several times and see if you see much difference when everything is cached.

Comment: The two plans you show both access an identical number of pages, 163,904.  It is just that the faster one finds them all in memory already, presumably because the slower on just got done putting them there.  You seem to have other questions as well, but without corresponding plans for them, I can't figure out what they are.  Maybe you should decompose this into multiple simpler questions.

Comment: In the cases you show, no recheck is actually performed.  It needs to be ready to do the recheck in case the bitmap should overflow (showing up as lossy blocks) but since all blocks are exact, no recheck is actually done.